# Exception in chef-automate runner installer

Tags: chef-infra

I'm executing below command command from chef-automate server to setup a runner and getting an exception in the log file.

**automate-ctl install-runner [chef-runner-IP] compliance --password --port 22 --yes**

can anyone help to solve this issue.

```
***********
```

ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::JSON::ParseError: lexical error: invalid char in json text.

---

Comment: Chef Automate is a commercial product of Chef Software Inc, as such most of the support volunteers for Chef (the project) don't really have much experience. You can reach Chef Software's support team at support@chef.io or by talking to your sales rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of incorrect organization mentioned in the deliverer.rb file. corrected the organization and reconfigured and fixed the issue.